# Java swing high quality PNG

Tags: java, image, swing, png

I have been trying to export my swing 2d diagram to a png file. I tried the following code :

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(width,height,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D referenceGraphics = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
referenceGraphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
paintComponent(referenceGraphics);

File imageFile = new File(fileName);
if (imageFile.exists() || imageFile.createNewFile()) {
    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", imageFile);
}
```

However the png file is been created successfully, but the quality is too low. I need to create at least 300ppi image file. How to achieve that?

Comment: Increasing the `width` and `height` would be what you want, but we have no way of knowing if it would be rendered at the size or if it would be rendered at the same size with the rest being empty space. This depends on your `paintComponent` method.

Comment: It also depends on your viewer.  What displays this PNG image, and how does it decide what pixels per inch to use?  There are standards, but often multiple standards and it's hard to ascertain which one will be used.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the image?

Answer (score 0):

Simply increasing the size of the component won't make the resolution of the image any better. It will just be larger. What you need to do is create the `BufferedImage` larger that the component (i.e. 3 times for 3 times the current resolution) and the scale the `Graphics` object of the `BufferedImage`. The resulting code would look something like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Component comp = ...
    BufferedImage img = scaledImageFromComponent(comp, 3);
    File imageFile = new File(fileName);
    if (imageFile.exists() || imageFile.createNewFile()) {
        ImageIO.write(img, "png", imageFile);
    }
}

public static BufferedImage scaledImageFromComponent(final Component c, final double scale) {
    c.setSize(c.getPreferredSize());
    c.doLayout();
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(0, 0, c.getWidth(), c.getHeight());
    return scaledImageFromComponent(c, r, scale, scale, false);
}

public static BufferedImage scaledImageFromComponent(final Component c, final Rectangle bounds,
                                                     final double scalex, final double scaley,
                                                     final boolean print) {
    BufferedImage image = createCompatibleTransparentImage((int) (scalex * bounds.width),
                                                           (int) (scaley * bounds.height));
    final Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
    g2d.scale(scalex, scaley);
    g2d.translate(-bounds.x, -bounds.y);
    if (print) {
        c.print(g2d);
    } else {
        c.paint(g2d);
    }
    g2d.dispose();
    return image;
}

public static BufferedImage createCompatibleTransparentImage(final int width,
                                                             final int height) {
    return isHeadless() ? new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB)
                        : getGraphicsConfiguration().createCompatibleImage(width, height,
                                                                           Transparency.BITMASK);
}

private static boolean isHeadless() {
    return GraphicsEnvironment.isHeadless();
}

private static GraphicsConfiguration getGraphicsConfiguration() {
    return GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration();
}
```

If your diagram contains text you may want to switch `Transparency.BITMASK` with `Transparency.OPAQUE` for better anti-aliasing support (on Windows).